# vuetify breakpoint undefined, TypeError: Cannot read property 'xsOnly' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
:class="{ 'pa-0': noPadding, 'pa-4': !noPadding && $vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly }"
```

in devtool i have error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'xsOnly' of undefined
```

what's the problem?

my app.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

version vuetify 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

You need first to import it through computed:

```
computed: {
    xsOnly() {
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly;
    }
}
```

And then use it to template:

```
:class="{ 'pa-0': noPadding, 'pa-4': !noPadding && xsOnly }"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that you simply need to prepend this: `:class="{ 'pa-0': noPadding, 'pa-4': !noPadding && this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly }"`
So you don't necessarily need a computed property for it.
And I'm sure you defined xsOnly in Vuetify so that it does not return 'undefined'